# Ubuntu 13.04 & Ehanced Desktop Zoom

Tags: unity, 13.04, fullscreen, zooming

With The new release of Ubuntu 13.04. Does the sidebar and top bar enlarge now when you zoom in using the Compiz enhanced desktop zoom. I saw that the new version uses Unity 7 so I'm really hoping the fixed this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool  < you will find most of settings init